# How do I enable thumbnails for 'webm' files?

Tags: icons, thumbnails, webm

I have thumbnails for every other file type just not `.webm`. Is there any way to enable them and if so, how would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

What file manager? This may be a simple matter of a missing feature. I know that Thunar and elementary's pantheon files use tumblerd to get thumbnails, and that an earlier version could not thumbnail webm files.

What version of your file manager and Ubuntu do you have?

Comment: ok, i figured it out. I was using an older verison of thunar.